# Updating Xcode from 4.1 to 4.2: No "Install Xcode.app" in Applications folder

Tags: xcode4

I've updated Xcode from 4.1 to 4.2 in Mac App Store but Xcode is still 4.1.

In Mac App Store now, no update available anymore. Xcode in Mac App Store does not appear like installed application because the button is labeled as "FREE" then "INSTALL APP" not "INSTALLED" as expected. When I clicked "FREE" and then "INSTALL APP", it alerts

"**We could not complete you purchase**  
Xcode is already installed on this computer. Choose Software Update from the Apple menu to check for available updates."

I followed the instruction but there is no available update for Xcode. I also tried to restart my computer for a few times but no effect.

Edited: There is no **Install Xcode** in my Applications folder as well.

Is there any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: This question has been asked at least 3 or 4 times today alone, let alone before today. Please try searching the forum before you post your question. Here's the answer anyway: Look for **Install Xcode** in your Applications folder, and run that.

Comment: @MarkGranoff **Install Xcode** cannot be found in my Applications folder.

Comment: In the App Store, try going to the Store menu and selecting Check for unfinished downloads.

Comment: @MarkGranoff Instead of Applications folder, **Install Xcode** appears in Launchpad.

Comment: Even more odd, but I guess under Lion that makes a little bit of sense... Good to know! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me answer my question.

In my case, instead of **Applications** folder, **Install Xcode** appears in **Launchpad**. So if you cannot find Install Xcode in your Application folder, take a look at your Launchpad.

Comment: And if one renamed the 4.1 "Install Xcode.app" (to "xcode 4.1 for lion installer") thinking that one could keep it for downgrade/re-install if necessary, one finds that app store updated the installer internally despite its name, making it a 4.2.1 xcode installer that ought to be run rather than ignored during hours of troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly 4.1 was before the mac app store and they may not have built in an easy way to cleanly update between the two.   You could move the 4.1 app to your desktop temporarily and see if the 4.2 install will go through and install itself, or uninstall 4.1 completely (make sure your projects are not saved within).  Or also see if in the mac app store it has a check for updates not the same as Software Update.